# Help wiring a pendant light

Tags: wiring

[image]I’m installing a pendant light.  I took down the old light and I’m having trouble figuring out how to wire the new one.

My ceiling has a white, black and copper ground wire.
My pendant light has a copper wire, then a black, white *and* green wire.  The black white and green wires are plastic wrapped and all are encased in the cord that goes to the bulb.

What do I do with the green wire?

The instructions say “connect the wires” which is super helpful.

Comment: If you add the country you are living in, you can increase chances for answers. That's because the wire colors differ somewhat depending on local legislation and codes.

Answer (score 18):

The bare wire is grounding/earthing the metal frame of the lamp, while the green wire which is part of the cable is grounding the handing pendant itself.

Since the frame and pendant are presumably connected only by the insulation of the hanging wire otherwise one or the other would have been un-earthed. Hence the two earthing wires need to be attached together and then to the earth from the supply wire.

Answer (score 15):

The green wire gets connected to the copper wire from you fixture and to the copper wire from the ceiling. Use the wire nut from the old fixture.  You also hook black to black and white to white. Make sure the power is off.